# How to check if an Email is activated with imessage programmatically?

Tags: ios, email, applescript, imessage

I try to test imessage for awhile by sending message from command line in Mac. If the receiver's apple account is activated with imessage, message sent successfully. Thus, could we check if receiver's email is activated with imessage ?

Answer (score 2):

with osascript:

**status** and **service type**

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to return {service type, status} of (service of some buddy whose handle contains "buddy@mac.com")'
```

Comment: I continue to get 38:120: execution error: Can’t get {iMessage, available} whose handle contains <the-number>

Comment: this won't crash <=> when value given after contains will evaluate to iMessage service; for the one with SMS it will fail.

Comment: to get "SMS" vs "E:youremailforImessage" use: `tell application "Messages" to return {name, status} of (service of some buddy whose handle contains "+<SOME_PHONE>")` be aware if multiple present, e.g you chat once with smbd using iMessage and once SMS, you have no guarranty what applescript will return

Comment: to get all possible for certain buddy phone use: `tell application "Messages" to return {name, status} of (service of buddies whose handle contains "+<PHONE>")` will return smth like: `{{"E:yourappleimessage@gmail.com", "SMS"}, {available, available}}`

Answer (score 1):

if you go in to imessage and type in the email, it will tell you if it is imessage or not.

Comment: I can see its color in blue if it's imessage, but only if we open imessage. cand we check by code ?